# How to give a angularjs data binded value in href of anchor tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to send a angularjs binded value which has mailid's seperated by , to mailto of anchor tag.

team.emails will have a single mail id or many mail id's seperated by comma.

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teamsData">
<td>{{team.name}}</td>
<td><a href='mailto:{{team.emails}}'</a></td>
</tr>
```

On clicking that column in the row should open outlook with the team email addresses in To part.
Kindly let me know if this is the correct approach.

Comment: You have forgatted to close <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "myapp" ng-controller="homeController">
 <table style="width:100%">
<tr ng-repeat="team in teamsData">
<td>{{team.name}}</td>
<td><p>
<a href="mailto:{{team.emails}}" target="_top">
Send Mail</a>
</p></td>
</tr> 
</table>  
</body>
<script>
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.teamsData = [{
  name:'john',
  emails:'xxx@gmail.com,yyy.gmail.com,zzz.gmail.com'
 },
 {
  name:'mark',
  emails:'lll@gmail.com,ppp.gmail.com,ooo.gmail.com'
 }]
}])
</script>
</html>
```